# Does renouncing one's US citizenship have the same tax implications as renouncing one's US lawful permanent resident status (=giving up green card)?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, france, citizenship

Does renouncing [one's US citizenship](https://www.usa.gov/renounce-lose-citizenship) have the same tax implications as [renouncing one's US lawful permanent resident status](https://www.uscis.gov/i-407) (i.e., giving up one's green card)?

If that matters (e.g., for tax treaties):

- The US lawful permanent resident or US citizen is also a French citizen.
- The individual will keep assets both inside and outside the United States.
- The individual doesn't know yet whether they'll be working for a US or non-US company, and where they'll physically be located.

---

https://www.lawyers.com/legal-info/immigration/citizenship/advantages-and-disadvantages-to-u-s-citizenship.html ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201227061219/https://www.lawyers.com/legal-info/immigration/citizenship/advantages-and-disadvantages-to-u-s-citizenship.html)) claims that:

> Once you become a U.S. citizen, it's difficult to ever escape your tax liability to the U.S. government, even if you voluntarily give up your citizenship. A green card holder, on the other hand, can give up his or her green card and not have to worry about filing U.S. tax returns after that.

but it does not give any details.

Comment: I believe there's even another layer for green cards. I think it might make a difference for exit tax implications if you actively renounce or the US gov actively revokes it, versus leaving the US and letting it expire and not renewing.

Comment: @TTT thanks good point, I'm curious about both cases.

Comment: I seem to recall that there are special rules regarding income tax for those who renounce their US citizenship for the purpose of avoiding US taxation, and I think the same applies to to those who give up their permanent resident status in the US.

Comment: The question does not distinguish between giving up citizenship while #1 staying in the country with all assets, #2 moving to another country but working for a US company, and leaving assets in the US, #3 moving to another country and working for a company in that country, but leaving assets in the US, and #4 moving person, employment and assets to another country.  Since it's such a huge topic, "Vote To Close - Needs Detail or Clarity".

Comment: @RonJohn I've just added the information you asked to the question.

Comment: VTC retracted.  Any answer would depend on whether you are a US Tax Resident or a Non-Resident Alien.  https://www.wealthspire.com/blog/tax-implications-investing-non-resident-alien/

Comment: @RonJohn thanks, does a former US lawful permanent resident would be treated differently from that standpoint compared to a former US citizen?

Comment: Of course that depends on whether or not you still own assets in the US (because those assets earn money, and taxes must be paid on them).

Comment: @RonJohn The individual will keep assets both inside and outside the United States.

Comment: If you own assets in the US, you've got to pay income tax on the earnings.  That's not rocket science.

Comment: @RonJohn thanks, will a former US lawful permanent resident be treated differently from that standpoint compared to a former US citizen?

Comment: The IRS does not care.

Comment: @RonJohn thank you, you're welcome to convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Whilz](https://www.reddit.com/user/Whilz) [points out](https://redd.it/ih8ul1) an interesting difference:

> There will be an exit tax if you relinquish and you were 1) a US citizen, or 2) a long-term resident, which means a green card for 8 or more years in the 15 year period immediately prior to expatriation.

Comment: In addition to an exit tax, renunciation of citizenship also requires full filing and payment of all tax years from the last 7 up to the current. This is particularly relevant for US citizens who have lived abroad perhaps their whole lives, and never knew they needed to file US taxes until now.